# SpreeCommerce Git Error i don't know why this error taken

Tags: linux, github, spree

```
casionwoo@casionwoo-desktop:~/mystore$ sudo spree install --auto-accept
 gemfile  spree
 gemfile  spree_gateway
 gemfile  spree_auth_devise
     run  bundle install from "."
sh: 1: git: not found
https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git (at 2-0-stable) is not 
checked out. Please run `bundle install`
casionwoo@casionwoo-desktop:~/mystore$ bundle install
Fetching https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git
sh: 1: git: not found
Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git'
"/home/casionwoo/.bundler/cache/git/spree_gateway-   
d999041097460b78cc4cd130c71269cf9c83fdb0" --bare
--no-hardlinks` in directory /home/casionwoo/mystore has failed.
```

i don't know how can i fix this error
is there anyone who know how can fix? and why this error occured?

Answer (score 0):

do you have installed git?

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: if you have installed git then maybe git is not in PATH, try the following: `cd /usr/bin && sudo ln -s ``which git`` git`   the doublé backticks should be single (format issue)